# how to add filter on measure in power BI?

Tags: filter, powerbi, measure

I have Power BI report having some filters implemented on columns. Now I have to add a new filter on the basis of measure, I have data in the following format for that column, `+ve integer`, `-ve integer` or `0`. 
What I'm trying to achieve, there should be a filter with three default values (`+ve integers`, `-ve integers` and `0`). 
When I select `+ve`, it should show only records having `+ve` integer values and so on for two other cases.

**Problem:** I am creating measure from a measure but not getting the exact data from it.

The second thing I did was created a measure of positive and negative, I am getting the exact data if I will use in table visual but not in the slicers form.

Answer (score 0):

Measures are not meant to be used as slicers. A best practice for Power BI is that if you need to filter by a certain criteria then you should create a new column in the data to reflect which values you want to filter by. 


If you have a very large data set then I would do this in the Query Editor using a conditional column. [image]

If you size isn't a factor then make a calculated column like so,

```
Answer =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    'Table'[Values] > 0, "Postive",
    'Table'[Values] < 0, "Negative",
    "Zero"
)
```

Now insert the column into the filter and you should be able to easily switch between what you need.